# How to recover/ restore Application.Current.LocalFolder on windows 8 app development

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have mistakenly deleted Application.Current.LocalFolder on my machine. When my windows 8 application starts, it will try to create some files in the LocalFoder. Since this folder is deleted, app is crashing.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me restore/ re create Application.Current.LocalFolder

Comment: Um, create a new folder and retitle it LocalFolder and place it in Application/Current? You could also try to do it programmatically in c#. When you create the files, check if the folder exists. If not, create it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Application.Current.LocalFolder is not a folder path. Windows 8 tablet apps store it's application data in some folder under your login account details and Application.Current.LocalFolder would help access this application data.

Comment: I tried to create this application data folder programmatically but windows 8 tablet app has still not recognized this folder. I read on microsoft forums, that folders can't be tempered and it has to be created by the windows 8 app itself

Comment: did you try to uninstall and then reinstall your app?